# Можно ли дистанционно установить windows на машину без ОС?

Tags: windows, установка, ос

Можно ли установить Windows на комп удаленно (первую, голый BIOS или UEFI)? Просто обратились из другого города, физического доступа к машине нет. Я думаю, стоит найти рабочий компьютер и сбросить образ человеку на почту, проконсультировать, что нажимать, но вдруг в современных ноутах можно получить удаленный доступ, кто сталкивался?

Comment: Вроде нельзя. Можно собрать образ винды с файлом ответов, который установит сам себя автоматически без лишних вопросов, но, подозреваю, делать это вслепую не очень хорошая идея

Comment: @andreymal Ок, значит будем на почту сбрасывать)

Comment: Хороший вопрос, кстати. Погрузил меня в раздумья....

Comment: сформировать AIK-образ и передать его клиенту. Либо установить самостоятельно ОС на аналогичное железо (с интеграцией драйверов сетевых интерфейсов). Затем передать образ со скриптом авторазвёртывания (Clonezilla,etc.). После в режиме поддержки удаленного рабочего стола завершить процесс. Можно и проще - отдать на откуп в аутсорс.

Comment: Есть такая штука, как `Intel vPro`, но к ней всё равно нужна инфраструктура. Так что технически: да. По факту: нет.